# Android build error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:androidJacocoAgent'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jacoco

Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:androidJacocoAgent'.

> Could not find org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Documents/android-studio_new/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
>         file:/home/locationXXX/Documents/android-studio_new/gradle/m2repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
>     Required by:
>         MyHome:app:unspecified

Am getting this error after upgrading the studio to 2.2.3
Gradle version  2.14.1
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Below is my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/androidasync-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}




buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myhome"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/androidasync-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated Android gradle build tool to 2.2.3 after updating gradle version to 2.14.1

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Add this line above appcompact line like this

```
compile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.5.201505241946'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Yes, gradle build is 2.2.3

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }

Comment: do you see any issue in build.gradle file?

Comment: check your root build.gradle, Have you added repository there ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I didn't get that, could you please elaborate?

Comment: check my updated answer, then after injection of dependency refresh gardle

Comment: @Pradeep what is the status ?

Comment: It Worked!!! My Project structure is of old version since it was migrated from eclipse. Your idea of creating root build.gradle file helped me. Thanks!!! Marking that as answer.

Comment: It's ok with old version just add repository in same build.gradle and the above given dependency